# Adding the localized Display Name to the constraint violation message?

Tags: validation, gwt

We are using the new GWT validation library in 2.5.

We are adding an aggregated list of violations to our screen. This list must display the localized field name.

```
@MyNotNull(foo= "Stage")
public String getStage();
```

Localized message needs to display

"Stage is a required field"

The message in MyValidationMessages.properties reads

> {foo} is a required field

Note that annotations do not allow non-constant values to be assigned to attributes. So we have to get the locale value somehow at design time :/

This will not work

```
@MyNotNull(foo = injector.getLocale().errorMessage()) 
public String errorMessage()
```

How do I use localeKey to look up the locale in the locale files since the property requires a constant?

Comment: Please add relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to

- add something like FieldLocale.properties this is a constants lookup
- Add an attribute to your annotation like localeKey
- Iterate your ConstraintViolation collection
- Use something like the below to get the attribute value
- Look up the localized value in your FieldLocale.properties file
- Copy the violation and change the message to the localized version

  protected String getAttributeValue(ConstraintViolation violation, String key) {
          ConstraintDescriptor descriptor = violation.getConstraintDescriptor();

  ```
      if (descriptor.getAttributes().containsKey(key))
          return (String) descriptor.getAttributes().get(key);

      return null;
  }

  protected ConstraintViolation<T> copyMessage(ConstraintViolation<T> violation, String message) {
      return ConstraintViolationImpl.<T> builder() //
              .setConstraintDescriptor(violation.getConstraintDescriptor()) //
              .setInvalidValue(violation.getInvalidValue()) //
              .setLeafBean(violation.getLeafBean()) //
              .setMessage(message) //
              .setMessageTemplate(violation.getMessageTemplate()) //
              .setPropertyPath(violation.getPropertyPath()) //
              .setRootBean(violation.getRootBean()) //
              .setRootBeanClass(violation.getRootBeanClass()) //
              .build();
  }
  ```